# Finding lines that include two or more words from a list

Tags: python

I have written this code which checks which lines in an infile matches all of the keywords in a keyword file. Now, I want it instead to find all lines that just include two or more of the keywords in any combination.

```
infile = open('/Path/#input.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('/Path/#output.txt', 'w')

# Read a textfile containing keywords to find
# (and strip the newline character '\n')
keywords = [line.strip() for line in open('Path/#keywords.txt')]

# See which lines in the infile match ALL of the keywords
# and write those lines to the outfile
for line in infile:
    if all(k in line for k in keywords):
        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way

```
if len(set(line.split()).intersection(keywords)) > 2:
```

This splits the line into words with `line.split()` first
. Then uses [sets intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) function to find the common elements of 2 sets

Comment: I think you are missing a `)` after split()

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand this, but is finding the common elements of 2 sets the same thing as finding lines in the infile that contains at least 2 of the words in the keyword file?

Comment: @textnet a line can be interpreted as a list of words (this is done by the `.split()`function), and a list can be converted to a set